# Objective C: splitting an array into subarrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have a text file looking like this :

```
#AAA:x
12
34
7
...
#BBB:y
-74.7
-33.2
14
...
#CCC:z
32.4
17
...
#END
```

I'm able to put all of it in one big `NSArray` (using `componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"`)

Now I'd like to have:

AAA float NSArray with all the values under the tag `#AAA:x`;

BBB float NSArray with all the values under the tag `#BBB:y`; etc..

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you consider splitting at `#`, then splitting at `\n` and ignoring the first line?

Comment: i think this could actually works !
But how can I split an NSArray in 3NSArray based on a char value ('#' here) ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer :s
In apple documentation I only saw : "subarrayWithRange(NSRange arg0)" that sounds close to what I wanna do but it uses NSrange instead of NDString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, try this:

```
NSMutableArray *subarrays = [[myTest componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"] mutableCopy];
for (int i = 0; i < subarray.length; i++) {
    NSArray *subarray = [subarrays[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    subarray = [subarray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, subarray.length-1)];
    subarrays[i] = subarray;
}
```

This should result in an array of string arrays.

So `subarrays[0]` will be an array of strings with these elements: 12, 34, 7.
subarrays[1][2] will be a string "14"

If you want floats and not strings, you will have to additionally iterate over all the entries  and convert them to float. You can use `NSString`'s `floatValue` method to do that.

Comment: Thenk you for your help.
Few modifications to make on your example (if someone need them one day)
`NSMutableArray *subarrays = [[myTest componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"]mutablecopy];`
and `NSArray *subarray = [[subarrays objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];`

Comment: I added your first suggestion to my post. The second one should work however as I suggested since Xcode 4.4.